# affect all classes before or after

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying to make a filter for my svg map and i would like to press the filter and all classes after the one i pressed, change to gray, for exemplo:

i have the classes { varcor2, varcor2e1, varcor2e2, varcor2e3, varcor2e4, varcor2e5, varcor2e6, varcor2e7, varcor2e8, varcor2e9, varcor3, etc... } (i have more then this one's)

and i would like to press for example, varcor2e5 and all the path with the classe's varcor2e6, varcor2e7, varcor2e8, varcor2e9, varcor3, etc... .css("fill", "#969696") and the varcor2e5 and before that .css("fill", "") so he can get the respective color from css

Now i can afect only the one i pressed, i tryed to use .next(), .nextAll(), .prev() and .prevAll() but it didnt worked out

can someone help me with this script?

```js
$(".coresfiltro").click(function () {
    // var n = $(".coresfiltro").length;
    $(this).prevAll().removeClass("pintarnoclick").removeClass("ultimofiltroescolhido");
    $(this).nextAll().addClass("pintarnoclick").removeClass("ultimofiltroescolhido");
    $(this).addClass("ultimofiltroescolhido");
    $('.coresfiltro').removeClass("clickedfiltrocor");
    $(this).addClass("clickedfiltrocor");
    if ($('#cor2e0').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e1').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e1').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e2').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e2').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e3').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e3').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e4').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e4').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e5').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e5').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e6').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e6').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e7').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e7').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e8').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e8').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor2e9').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor2e9').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    } else if ($('#cor3e0').hasClass('clickedfiltrocor')) {
        $('.varcor3').addClass("selectedfiltrocor");
        $('path').not(".selectedfiltrocor").css("fill", "#969696");

    }
});
```

```css
.mapasvg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

.mapasvg svg {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  fill: #969696;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.mapasvg svg #AF {
  fill: #BE24A0;
}

.mapasvg svg #AE {
  fill: #C83487;
}


.escalageral {
  display: flex;
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 400px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.escalamap {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.escalamap .mapscale {
  background: #4945c5;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #4945c5 0%, #9c22b9 50%, #eb6b33 85%, #fff701 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.escalamap .filtroporcores {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.escalamap .filtroporcores .coresfiltro {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="mapasvg" id="mapaworld">
                        <?xml version="1.0"?>
                        <svg baseprofile="tiny" fill="#ececec" height="857" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round"
                            stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".2" version="1.2" viewbox="0 0 2000 857" width="2000"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                                d="M1383 261.6l1.5 1.8-2.9 0.8-2.4 1.1-5.9 0.8-5.3 1.3-2.4 2.8 1.9 2.7 1.4 3.2-2 2.7 0.8 2.5-0.9 2.3-5.2-0.2 3.1 4.2-3.1 1.7-1.4 3.8 1.1 3.9-1.8 1.8-2.1-0.6-4 0.9-0.2 1.7-4.1 0-2.3 3.7 0.8 5.4-6.6 2.7-3.9-0.6-0.9 1.4-3.4-0.8-5.3 1-9.6-3.3 3.9-5.8-1.1-4.1-4.3-1.1-1.2-4.1-2.7-5.1 1.6-3.5-2.5-1 0.5-4.7 0.6-8 5.9 2.5 3.9-0.9 0.4-2.9 4-0.9 2.6-2-0.2-5.1 4.2-1.3 0.3-2.2 2.9 1.7 1.6 0.2 3 0 4.3 1.4 1.8 0.7 3.4-2 2.1 1.2 0.9-2.9 3.2 0.1 0.6-0.9-0.2-2.6 1.7-2.2 3.3 1.4-0.1 2 1.7 0.3 0.9 5.4 2.7 2.1 1.5-1.4 2.2-0.6 2.5-2.9 3.8 0.5 5.4 0z"
                                id="AF" class="mediooriente varcor2e4" name="Afghanistan" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top" data-html="true"
                                title='<span class="tooltip2linha">2,4</span>Afeganistão'>
                            </path>
                            <path class="Angola"
                                d="M 1121.2 572 1121.8 574 1121.1 577.1 1122 580.1 1121.1 582.5 1121.5 584.7 1109.8 584.6 1109 605.1 1112.6 610.3 1116.2 614.3 1105.8 616.9 1092.3 616 1088.5 613 1065.8 613.2 1065 613.7 1061.7 610.8 1058.1 610.6 1054.7 611.7 1052 612.9 1051.5 608.9 1052.4 603.2 1054.4 597.3 1054.7 594.6 1056.6 588.8 1058 586.2 1061.3 582 1063.2 579.1 1063.8 574.4 1063.5 570.7 1061.9 568.4 1060.4 564.5 1059.1 560.7 1059.4 559.3 1061.1 556.8 1059.5 550.6 1058.3 546.3 1055.5 542.2 1056.1 541 1058.4 540.1 1060.1 540.2 1062.1 539.5 1078.8 539.6 1080.1 544.3 1081.7 548.2 1083 550.3 1085.1 553.6 1088.9 553.1 1090.7 552.2 1093.8 553.1 1094.7 551.5 1096.2 547.8 1099.7 547.5 1100 546.4 1102.9 546.4 1102.4 548.7 1109.2 548.6 1109.3 552.7 1110.4 555.1 1109.5 559 1109.9 563 1111.7 565.4 1111.3 573 1112.7 572.4 1115.1 572.6 1118.6 571.6 1121.2 572 Z">
                            </path>
                            <path class="Angola"
                                d="M 1055.3 539 1053.8 534.2 1056.1 531.4 1057.8 530.3 1059.9 532.5 1057.9 533.9 1056.9 535.5 1056.7 538.3 1055.3 539 Z">
                            </path>
                            <path
                                d="M1088 228l0.4 1.2 1.4-0.6 1.2 1.7 1.3 0.7 0.6 2.3-0.5 2.2 1 2.7 2.3 1.5 0.1 1.7-1.7 0.9-0.1 2.1-2.2 3.1-0.9-0.4-0.2-1.4-3.1-2.2-0.7-3 0.1-4.4 0.5-1.9-0.9-1-0.5-2.1 1.9-3.1z"
                                id="AL" name="Albania">
                            </path>
                            <path
                                d="M1296.2 336.7l1.3 5.1-2.8 0 0 4.2 1.1 0.9-2.4 1.3 0.2 2.6-1.3 2.6 0 2.6-1 1.4-16.9-3.2-2.7-6.6-0.3-1.4 0.9-0.4 0.4 1.8 4.2-1 4.6 0.2 3.4 0.2 3.3-4.4 3.7-4.1 3-4 1.3 2.2z"
                                id="AE" class="mediooriente varcor6e6" name="United Arab Emirates" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top" data-html="true"
                                title='<span class="tooltip2linha">6,6</span>Emirados Árabes Unidos'>
                            </path>
                            <path class="Argentina americadosul varcor6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                data-html="true" title='<span class="tooltip2linha">6</span>Argentina'
                                d="M 669.1 851.7 666.1 851.5 661.1 851.5 655.1 837.9 658.2 840.7 662.5 845.3 670.3 849 677.6 850.5 676.8 853.5 672.4 853.8 669.1 851.7 Z">
                            </path>
     
                        </svg>
                    </div>
  <div class="escalageral">
                            
                            <div class="escalamap">
                                <div class="filtroporcores">
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,1"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,2"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,3"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,4"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,5"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,6"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e7" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,7"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e8" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,8"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor2e9" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2,9"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,1"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,2"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,3"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,4"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,5"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,6"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e7" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,7"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e8" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,8"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor3e9" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="3,9"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,1"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,2"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,3"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,4"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,5"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,6"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e7" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,7"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e8" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,8"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor4e9" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="4,9"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,1"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,2"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,3"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,4"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,5"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,6"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e7" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,7"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e8" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,8"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor5e9" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="5,9"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,1"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,2"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,3"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,4"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,5"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,6"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e7" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,7"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e8" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,8"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor6e9" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="6,9"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,1"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,2"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,3"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,4"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,5"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,6"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e7" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,7"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e8" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,8"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor7e9" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="7,9"></div>
                                    <div class="coresfiltro" id="cor8e0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="8"></div>
                                    <!-- <div class="filtrocoracor" id="escolherofiltro"></div> -->

                                </div>
                                <div class="mapscale">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
```

i tried put some of my svg (it is a world map) and i put there my menu, it work's with the click

Answer (score 1):

For selecting prev/next items your should use prevAll and nextAll as you said. So something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/3xw8cp9n/

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function (e) {
  $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  $(this).prevAll().css("background-color", "green");
  $(this).nextAll().css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: I'm using <div> should i be using <li>? this is part of my color menu... i'm going to put some of my html on the question as well maybe could help with the answer

Comment: and my target are the classes but my click is on ID, because im using fill on path, and some path dont have any class because i dont want

Comment: Post some html. It'll be easier to make the js for your html. Or look at Marshall Fungai's answer. (my answer is just common solution for list of items, not for your svg map)

Comment: its there on the question, im using one svg, the thing you did i already did it on my code i just did put it because of the caracters

Comment: I don't get it. Can you be more specific? Like you want to fill (on click) other counties that wasn't clicked and doesn't have some class/id? That can be done with example above and $.each https://api.jquery.com/each/ (for each element that have your class)

Comment: yea, im not that good with jquery, i know i can use each but i dont understand how it works and i tried const and var and let as well and it didnt work, stackoverflow was my last option of a awnser

Answer (score 1):

prevAll() and nextAll() should work for you. But I modified your script
with a longer solution with a lot of assumptions. Test and add to it, maybe it will work for you. it involves finding the number of elements you want to change using the parent (first line) and also finding the index of the clicked item, then stepping up and down with a loop. The loops can be changed, but you got the idea.

```
 let numberOfChildren = $('.parentOfTargetChildren').children().length;  //Assuming you have the parent of the elements you want to target
 $(".coresfiltro").click(function () {
     
         let clickedIndexRelatedToSiblings = $(this).index();   /// index of the element in relation to its siblings
    
         //Step down the tree
         let i_prev  = clickedIndexRelatedToSiblings; 
         while (i_prev >= 0) {
            $(`.parentOfTargetChildren:nth-child("`+ i_prev +`")`).removeClass("pintarnoclick").removeClass("ultimofiltroescolhido");  
            i_prev--;
          }  
    
          //Step up the tree
          let i_next  = clickedIndexRelatedToSiblings; 
          while (i_next < numberOfChildren) {
             $(`.parentOfTargetChildren:nth-child("`+ i_next +`")`).addClass("pintarnoclick").removeClass("ultimofiltroescolhido");  
             i_next++;
          }  
     
    
        //Your code  
    
        $(this).addClass("ultimofiltroescolhido");
        $('.coresfiltro').removeClass("clickedfiltrocor");  //why remove this class and add it in the next line??  They reference the same object
        $(this).addClass("clickedfiltrocor"); 

    //......
    //rest of the code  

 });
```

Comment: the begging of my script its the efect to pint the bar, and now i want to use the selected filter to filter the path's with it, when it start if (hasClass) its where i need help, i dont know how i can use strings with class and id, like i want to link the ID with all class's of the respective ID and all above, if a press ID varcor2e0 the class corvar2 will change but if i press ID varcor2e8, the class corvar2e8 and all above will change